# What would have fought off Ungoliant had she consumed the Silmarils

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Ungoliant had the unique feat of consuming powers of other things. Had Melkor not withstood her, and handed her the Silmarils, (it's a long debate, but for the question's sake, let's assume this) she would have devoured and consumed the Silmarils. Having consumed the Silmarils, she would have become immensely strong. If that be the case, how many beings were there at that time (excluding Eru) which would have overcome Ungoliant in a one on one duel?

PS: I am new to Tolkien's World, therefore I am sorry if my ignorance is borderline offensive.

Comment: if she was stronger then melkor before she consumed the silmarils she would not have been beaten 1v1 by any of the other Ainur.
She probably would have beaten anyone 1v1 without consuming the silmarils anyway if she could beat melkor, so the silmarils are an extra point.

Comment: Tulkas is a strong contender

Comment: I'm not sure why she would have become immensely strong. What do you have to support that?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?” - I'm not sure this merits a VTC but it's certainly borderline.

Comment: Interesting question certainly the sons of Feanor would pursue her with the forces of the noldor & possibly the elves of Bereland  inevitably theyd lose but i dont think the Valar would sit by idly & let her decimate the whole lot. In the end theyd intervene & imo the valar combined would annihilate her.

Comment: Whoops i just re read ur question.1 v 1.Tulkas Orome possibly Eonwe.Melkor poured alotve strength into her but she ran from the balrogs so im not too sure of her strength plus idk if the silmarillion would give her a gr8 deal of strength because inher case if she consumed them they wouldve been destroyed.

Answer (score 9):

It's established in *The Silmarillion* that by the time Melkor and Ungoliant fought, a lot of power had already gone out of Melkor and he was therefore a significantly weaker being than he had formerly been.

Let's backtrack to before then, when we see just how powerful he once was:

> Then Ilúvatar spoke, and he said: "Mighty are the Ainur, and mightiest among them is Melkor..." (*Ainulindalë*)

And:

> The mightiest of those Ainur who came into the World was in his beginning Melkor... (*Valaquenta*)

And:

> And he shut the doors of his house in the face of the mightiest of all the dwellers in Eä. ("Of the Silmarils and the Unrest of the Noldor")

So it's clear that even up to the point of just before the slaying of the Trees, Melkor still retained his former stature.  However that was soon to change; after the Trees are killed we see:

> And still she thirsted, and going to the Wells of Varda she drank them dry; but Ungoliant belched forth black vapours as she drank, and swelled to a shape so vast and hideous that Melkor was afraid. ("Of the Darkening of Valinor")

At this point Melkor is definitely a lesser being than he had formerly been, and during the Thieves' Quarrel we read:

> But Ungoliant had grown great, and **he less by the power that had gone out of him**; and she rose against him, and her cloud closed about him, and she enmeshed him in a web of clinging thongs to strangle him. ("Of the Flight of the Noldor")

What was this "power that had gone out of him"?  It's answered earlier in the same chapter when Melkor says to her:

> Thou hast had thy due. For **with my power that I put into thee** thy work was accomplished. I need thee no more.

A central part of the concept of Middle-earth is that it was forever marred by Melkor distributing his power into it, so that he became a much lesser being than his former stature, and here we see that he had already begun doing so.  This is covered in the later parts of *History of Middle-earth 10: Morgoth's Ring* if you're interested in exploring this theme further.

---

That's a fairly lengthy preamble but with the purpose of establishing that by the time of the Thieves' Quarrel **Melkor was no longer the mightiest being in all of Arda**.  As a result of that, it should be evident that a being of lesser might than Melkor originally had would have the ability to defeat Ungoliant.

Consequently we should not assume that an Ungoliant who had devoured the Silmarils would have been undefeatable.

Tolkien didn't deal in ranking his villains and beasts in order of relative degrees of power, like a D&D Monster Manual would.  However, we see that in the published *Silmarillion* an Ungoliant who hadn't devoured the Silmarils was easily driven off by Balrogs (where Melkor failed to withstand them), and in certain versions of the Mythology she was ultimately slain by Eärendil (unlike the published version, where she devoured herself; interestingly and according to *History of Middle-earth 7* this story almost made it into *Lord of the Rings*).  This establishes that Melkor's difficulties with her were due to his own weaknesses more than to her overwhelming power; she certainly had become more powerful, but not *that* much more.

As for an Ungoliant who *had* devoured the Silmarils, what seems most likely is that they wouldn't grant her additional power but instead burn her from the inside-out:

> And Varda hallowed the Silmarils, so that thereafter no mortal flesh, nor hands unclean, nor anything of evil will might touch them, but it was scorched and withered... ("Of the Silmarils and the Unrest of the Noldor")

This would be in a similar manner to the wolf Carcharoth:

> Then swiftly all his inwards were filled with a flame of anguish, and the Silmaril seared his accursed flesh [...] Then Mablung took a knife and ripped up the belly of the Wolf; and within he was well nigh all consumed as with a fire... ("Of Beren and Lúthien")

I see no evidence to suppose that the eventual outcome would have been any different with Ungoliant.

Comment: Amazing, as usual...